# Lightbox not showing php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working for a system by the use of php. We have an admin.php page where all the list of applicants were listed. And we want that when we click on a specific applicant's name, a lightbox would appear that will show more information about the applicant. But, these codes below seems to be not working and I don't know why. I am a newbie in php btw.

```
 <?php

include('config.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee as t1")



or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='15' text-align = 'center' >";

echo "<tr>";
echo " <caption><b><font size = '5'> <h2>List of Applicants </h2> </b> </font><hr></caption>";

echo "<th>Applicant ID</th>";
echo "<th>Application Date</th>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Job</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{

echo "<tr class='gradeC'>";

echo '<td><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['employee_id'] . '</font></b></td>';
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['date'] . '</font></b></td>';
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300"><a href="admin.php?hello=true">' . $row['fname'] . '</a></font></b></td>';
echo '<td><td>';
echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
function runMyFunction() {
echo "<div onclick =\"document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'\"></div>";
echo "<div id=\"light\" class=\"white_content\">This is the lightbox content. <a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" onclick = \"document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'\">Close</a></div>";
echo "<div id=\"fade\" class=\"black_overlay\"></div>";

    }

  if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
      runMyFunction();
  }

 ?>
```

I'm not sure but I think the problem is in the function, or the way I'm using the codes for lightbox to appear.

Comment: You need to use a MySQLi or PDO system rather than MySQL straight as standard MySQL has now become ***deprecated*** and should not be used, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Can you rewrite this line

```
function runMyFunction() {
echo "<div onclick =\"document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'\"></div>";
echo "<div id=\"light\" class=\"white_content\">This is the lightbox content. <a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" onclick = \"document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'\">Close</a></div>";
echo "<div id=\"fade\" class=\"black_overlay\"></div>";

    }
```

to

```
function runMyFunction() {
?>
<div onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"></div>
<div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. 
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
<?php }
```

By eliminating the slashes could help make the code easier to process.

I hope this help.

Comment: I didn't get any error from php. But, it didn't showed up the lightbox either. runMyFunction is really working, but when I tried putting it inside my php codes, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you add this **error_reporting(E_ALL);** code on the top of include **config.php** or on the 1st line on the **config.php** and try to check if there a display. 
**$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee as t1")** don't have semi-column at the end.

Comment: Already did. Still, nothing happened. My list is working, it's just the lightbox that don't show up. See here: http://snag.gy/zjQUU.jpg

Comment: Updated my answer please do check and btw you're pinoy :)

Comment: Yes, I am same as you :) Btw, tried it, still not working. How it will work if the divs are outside the function? @yamidemichaos

Comment: It's still inside the function, it is just the same with echo or print but it is more cleaner than putting them inside the echo.

Comment: If you check your given image, there is **";** on the top and bottom of the text _This is the lightbox content. Close_ . I believe there is something to do with it, kind of missing or over using quotes.

Comment: I reviewed the codes, and put a closing div tag </div> after "This is a lightbox content" because on your given codes, it doesn't have a closing tag on it. The text is gone and it's still not working tho.